# How can I generate square pulses of the format shown in picture? The positive part should have smaller time scale

Tags: integrated-circuit, 555, pulse, function-generator, square

[image]

How can I generate pulses of this format? I need to generate **a single pulse** of 20V as a trigger pulse for performing a microscopy experiment( I couldn't manage to get a programmable function generator of my need).The negative part of the pulse( puse width) should be of 1 s long and positive part( pulse width) variable from 200 microsec to 100 ms.
Pls suggest the MCU that can be used for this. A little explanation or link to any pdf or video would be of much help as I don't have electronics/ electrical background. The important point is I need only one pulse at a time and not a series of pulses.

Comment: 555 controlled with pot in astable mode and connect its output to dual supplied comparator. Set reference level of comparator to half of positive rail.

Comment: With what precision or tolerance you need those pulses? What are the specs for the actual analog(or digital) waveform, such as voltages, rise/fall times, etc? In other words, why not simply use a MCU?

Comment: There is also possible to use just  555 itself but dual supplied.

Comment: really really sounds like a job for a simple microcontroller. The 555 solution to this is more complicated by a solid amount, both in number of components as well as in complexity of fine-tuning things to work over this large range of times. The [tag:555] is really not a common solution to real-world problems.

Comment: 15-25V range pulses, only one pulse at a  time- not a continuous series of pulses . Also I do not know much knowledge about microcontroller, not from electronics /electrical eng background.

Comment: Please add new information and clarifications to your question by [edit]ing it. Down here in the comments they are not seen. -- Please extend your question to show **all** relevant requirements, such as triggers, delays, voltages, currents, ...

Comment: Please explain the application, the kind of load and the required current. There are too many options to write an answer.

Comment: You say the positive part is +20V, but what voltage is the negative part?

Comment: @SimonFitch +20V and -20V for the positive and negative part respectively. I want to use this as a substitute for conventionally available pulse/ function generator. And most importantly I want to generate only one single pulse at a time, not a series of pulses.

Answer (score 4):

Whatever solution you use will probably consist of two parts. One part that uses a "typical" supply voltage, say 0V (ground) and 5V, or perhaps 0V and 12V. This part will be the pulse generator, responsible for generating a 200μs to 100ms pulse at a "typical" logic levels.

The second part will have to "level" translate that pulse to become required −20V and +20V. Let's start with the second part (level translator):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmjCuR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This takes a low level 0V/+5V (or 0V and any potential above zero, really) presented at input P, and produces a signal at OUT which is either -20V (when P is low) or +20V (for P high):

[image]

<sub>Note: There is a small 5μs delay before the output returns low again, due to deep saturation of the transistors. This can be mitigated, but not without complicating the design. You could always compensate for this delay in microcontroller software.</sub>

The first part, that produces a signal for P, can be implemented a dozen different ways, using a thousand different components at its core. If you want to automate the source of pulses, and have the most flexibility, then I recommend an Arduino, and spend a little time learning how to program it. It's probably the microcontroller solution with the quickest learning curve and build times, but I can't teach you the necessary skills here. Here's how you would connect it up to the module above, very simply:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp6XJt.png)</sup>

Then you must program the Arduino to produce the requisite 200μs to 100ms pulses at the GPIO output.

To do variable width pulse generation the hard way, using a discrete timer, is quite difficult, since there's a factor of 500 difference between 200μs and 100ms. Still, you can hack something together with a 555 timer IC:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhKvsC.png)</sup>

An output pulse is triggered by pressing switch SW1. Unfortunately, the 555 output remains high while its trigger input is low, potentially long after the output pulse duration should have expired, so the shenanigans going on with C1, R5, R6 and D1 is to ensure that the trigger input to the 555 timer doesn't last more than a few microseconds, even if SW1 is held closed.

The duration of the output pulse is controlled by VR1 and SW2. SW2 selects timing capacitor \$C_T\$, from one of C3, C4 and C5, each different in value by a factor of 10. VR1 permits control of the timing resistance, which is the sum of R7 and VR1. That is, you may obtain a timing resistance \$R_T\$ between about 3kΩ and about 50kΩ.

The output pulse duration \$T\$ is:

$$ T = 1.1 \times R_T \times C_T $$

You have three possible positions for SW3, and by varying VR1, you can obtain the following pulse durations:

\$C_T = 47nF\$ --> 170μs to 2.6ms

\$C_T = 470nF\$ --> 1.7ms to 26ms

\$C_T = 4.7\mu F\$ --> 17ms to 260ms

Answer (score -3):

[image]

Use a microcontroller. So I did in a couple of minutes.

[image]

Comment: Could use voodoo just as well. He probably doesn't know a thing about MCU, so s lot more explanation is needed

Comment: I am not ready to write a training course here. This is all on the Internet. I showed the simplest way and that it works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i see there is a series of pulse. I am trying to find a way to generate only one pulse ie not more than one pulse should be send by my circuit.

Comment: +1 for the "I don't give a damn" hygiene of the scope :D But agree, it's probably not of much help. @Gan look up how to use Timers/Counters of a microcontroller of your choice.

Comment: Excuse me, but you didn't "show" anything at all, it could be a printed diagram for all we know. At least show your source code and schematic.

Comment: The only thing you've shown is that you're capable of solving this problem. Congrats. This isn't a self promoting website but a Q&A site. Your "answer" can in no shape or form be considered an answer.

Comment: None of you offered anything at all. If someone needed it, he would have asked specific and to-the-point questions.

Comment: True. I am too lazy to write a full answer. However, let's put it this way. The op needs two rails - positive and negative, like +/-5V. Opamp that would translate 0 and 3. 3V signal to -something and +somethingelse. And then an MCU that either uses PWM peripheral or bithl-banging code to generate a digital signal.

Comment: If you look at my photo you will see that the signal there is bipolar, -1.5 and +1.5. Half of the power supply is taken as ground. You can do this, it works. Depending on the conditions of the problem, all this can be changed, but there are no conditions of the problem. What is ultimately needed is unknown.

Comment: The microcontroller can be absolutely anything, for example an Arduino, all you need from it is to jerk one leg with a delay. I did it on an STM8 because it was lying on the table.

Comment: See, all this should be on the answer :)